# Predict certain label with highest possible probability in logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am building the model, having 12 parameters and {0,1} labels using logistic regression in sklearn. I need to be very confident about label 0, I am ok if some '0' will be missclassified to 1. The purpose of this, that I would like to exclude the data from the processing if the data is classifies to 0.

How can I tune the parameters?

Comment: Your statement : `I need to be very confident about label 0, I am ok if some '0' will be missclassified to 1.` is contradicting. First you are saying that you need to be pretty sure about label 0 and then you are saying it's okay to miscalssify it.

Comment: sorry for confision. In other words, i want to sure: if I got 0 for test data, then the probability is very high, near to 99%, but if I got 1, I am ok with lower probabiliity. does it makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically looking for specificity, which is defined as the `TN/(TN+FP)`, where TN is True Negative and FP is False Positive. You can read more about this in this [blog post](http://corysimon.github.io/articles/classification-metrics/) and more in [detail here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity). To implement this you need to use [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) along with [confusion_matrix metric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) in sklearn as follows :

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

def get_TN_rate(y_true,y_pred):
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
    specificity = float(tn)/(float(tn)+float(fp))
    return specificity

tn_rate = make_scorer(get_TN_rate,greater_is_better=True)
```

Now you can use `tn_rate` as a scoring function to train your classifier.

Comment: How would you use this scorer in a `LogisticRegression` model? I cannot find any argument to put it in.